# Neural Network Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I got the following latex code for making neural network diagrams, but this particular code does not color the neural network, I only want the neurons to be colored not the dots (....) between them. Can anyone help me out with this? [image] Code is attached below.

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
{
  \node [every neuron/.try,neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
}
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$x_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$h_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$y_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Ouput}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzset{
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    blue,
    minimum size=1cm
  }`

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    blue, % <----------- Add the color you want.
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
{
  \node [every neuron/.try,neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
}
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$x_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$h_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$y_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Ouput}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]