# How can I draw using LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, geometry, graphs

I'm writing a paper and I'm kind of new to LaTeX. I wanted to know how these kinds of figures are made. Are they made in LaTeX? If yes, then how?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! There is already a large abundance of neuronal networks, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497859/194703.

Comment: Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543642/i-want-to-render-a-flow-chart-diagram-where-arrows-go-between-symbols-from-o/543647#543647

Comment: I guess we can reopen this, since the answer was very well received. The question still is lacking a MWE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are plenty of posts for each of these, now there is one more post. For instance, the neuronal network is very similar to the one of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497859/194703).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[neuron/.style={circle,inner sep=1em,draw},
    neuron missing/.style={
    scale=1.25,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=$\vdots$,
  }]
 \begin{scope}[x=3cm,y=2cm]  
 \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z,remember=\Y as \LastY] in {Input/2,Hidden/3,Hidden/4,Output/2} 
 {\foreach \YY in {1,...,\Y}
 {\node[neuron] (n-\Z-\YY) at (\Z,-\YY+\Y/2+1/2) {};
 \ifnum\YY=1
  \node[above=1em of n-\Z-\YY,font=\sffamily] {\X\ layer};
 \else
  \path (n-\Z-\the\numexpr\YY-1) -- (n-\Z-\YY) 
   node[midway,neuron missing] {};
 \fi
 \ifnum\Z>1
  \foreach \YYY in {1,...,\LastY}
  {\draw[-{Triangle},semithick] (n-\the\numexpr\Z-1\relax-\YYY) -- (n-\Z-\YY) ;}
 \fi
 }}
 \end{scope} 
 \path[nodes={inner sep=1pt}]
    (n-2-2.-80) node[below right]{$x_i^\ell$} 
    (n-3-3.-80) node[below right]{$x_j^{\ell+1}$}
    (n-3-3.west) node[left=2pt]{$w_{ij}^{\ell}$}
    (n-4-2.-90) node[below]{$\widehat{y_k}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=5em,minimum
    height=1.2em},arj/.style={semithick,-latex}]
  \begin{scope}[start chain=A going below,oc/.style={join=by arj,on chain},
    font=\sffamily,node distance=1.75em]
   \node[box,oc]{Layer};
   \node[box,oc,label={north west:{$F(x_\ell)$}}]{Layer};
   \node[circle,oc,draw,thick,node font=\bfseries\large,inner sep=1pt,
    label={left:{$F(x_\ell)+x_\ell$}}]{+};
   \node[oc]{$x_{\ell+1}$};
  \end{scope}   
  \draw[arj,latex-] (A-1.north) -- ++ (0,1.75em)
      coordinate[midway,label=left:{$x_\ell$}](aux);
  \draw[arj] (aux) -- ++ (2em,0) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=1.5]
  node[midway,right]{$h(x_\ell)=x_\ell$}(A-3);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As usual, excellent ....

Comment: Nicely done, the support you provide on our site is amazing, Kudos to you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps!