# How can I make this figure start from right to left

Tags: tikz-pgf, neuralnetwork

I want to produce this figure but I want it to start from right to left, not from left to right. How can I do that?

I have obtained the code from this answer on the [Visual representation of Deep Neural Network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660548/visual-representation-of-deep-neural-network/660554#660554)

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    blue, % <----------- Add the color you want.
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
{
  \node [every neuron/.try,neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
}
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};
  
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden2-\m) at (4,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (6,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$x_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  {\node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$h_{1\l}$};
  \node [above] at (hidden2-\i.north) {$h_{2\l}$};}

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$y_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (hidden2-\j);
    
\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden2-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Hidden, Ouput}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `xscale=-1` key to flip the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    blue, % <----------- Add the color you want.
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth,xscale=-1]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
{
  \node [every neuron/.try,neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
}
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};
  
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden2-\m) at (4,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (6,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$x_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  {\node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$h_{1\l}$};
  \node [above] at (hidden2-\i.north) {$h_{2\l}$};}

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$y_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (hidden2-\j);
    
\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden2-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Hidden, Ouput}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @user20155022 You're welcome!